# Is it possible to extract disk/RAID drivers from a windows server?

Tags: windows, drivers

Is it possible to extract drivers from a server?

I have an operational HP server that I want to repave but I can't seem to find a version of smartstart that enabled windows server installer to recognise the disk array (i.e. no disks/controllers are discovered), nor can I find any specific driver installation that works.

My hope is that I can extract the working disk / RAID drivers from the machine and load those drivers during the windows installation.

Any thoughts?

DC

Comment: Windows OS version and server model plz.  Sounds likely that you are attempting to install an unsupported OS?

Comment: They are HP ML110 and I am looking for 2008 R2 but 2012 or newer would be brilliant.

Comment: ML110 G5 specifically

Comment: Curious -- did you try the RAID driver on HP website?  http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=3577726&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4064

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self Answer: Yes, it is.  Turns out you can use powershell to extract any custom drivers installed.

The meat of it is:

`Get-WindowsDriver -online | % { 
   $dir = Split-Path $_.OriginalFileName -Parent ; 
   $subdir = Split-Path $dir -Leaf ; 
   $driverDest = "$destination\$subdir"; 
   Write-Host "Copying $dir to $driverDest\$subdir" ; 
   Copy-Item -Path $dir -Destination $driverDest -Recurse 
}`

Source: http://blogs.technet.com/b/mniehaus/archive/2013/09/16/grabbing-out-of-box-drivers-from-a-windows-8-system.aspx